# Existence of a subfield having certain properties

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I was going through the proof of the theorem which states that : "The finite dimensional extension L of K is separable iff the bilinear form $(x,y) = T_{L/K}(xy)$ is non degenerate".
The proof given in the book "Algebraic Number fields" by Gerald Janusz to prove the reverse implication involves assuming that L is non separable over K and arriving at a contradiction. While doing so, he states the existence of a subfield $F$ of $L$ containing K such that:

(a) $(L:F) = p^m \neq 1$
(b) for each $x \in L,x^p$ is in $F$

I do not understand how is it that such a field $F$ exists. It will be helpful if the construction of such a field can be explained.

Comment: The book is by Gerald Janusz. You have left out a vital piece of information: in this part of the proof Janusz is assuming the extension L is non-separable over K, in order to deduce that the form is degenerate, to establish a contradiction.

Comment: yeah noted that and have added that to the question. I still don't understand the existence of the field F though

Comment: Also to be noted is that p is the characteristic of L. Just take F to be the set of p'th powers of the elements of L.