# Not separable extension

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am reading Algebraic Number Fields by Gerald Janusz where I don't understand the part in the picture. The extension $L/K$ is finite. I know extensions of zero characterstic field are always separable so $K$ must have finite characterstic, but I don't know how $(a)$ $(b)$ come up.
[image]

Comment: This question has been asked before: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3834473/existence-of-a-subfield-having-certain-properties#comment7917966_3834473. I believe my comment there is an answer: take F to be the set of p'th powers of the elements of L.

Comment: True, but how can we show that this field satisfy (a) and contain K? Thank you :)

Comment: I guess @MichaelCohen wanted to set $F=L^pK$, to exactly avoid the possibility $F\not\supset K$.

Comment: @Lubin Indeed, and the last problem is how can we show this field is not exactly $L$ then? Non-separability is not used yet.

Comment: You write "extensions of infinite characterstic field are always separable".  While the term "infinite characteristic" was in use by some people 60 years ago, it has been obsolete for decades; fields that contain $\mathbf Q$ are said to have characteristic $0$, not characteristic infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E\subseteq L$ be the subfield consisting of elements that are separable over $K$.  Then $L/E$ is purely inseparable (and nontrivial since $L/K$ is not separable), so $L$ can be obtained from $E$ by repeatedly adjoining $p$th roots of elements.  The last step of such a process would be a subfield $F\subset L$ such that $L$ is obtained from adjoining a $p$th root $b$ to an element $a\in F$ which has no $p$th root in $F$.  Then $[L:F]=p$ and $L^p\subseteq F$ since $L=F(b)$ and $b^p\in F$ (and the $p$th power map is a ring homomorphism).